# Mouse moving and clicking on its own in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, multi-touch, elantech

I recently upgraded from 12.10 where I had been having some mild touchpad problems.  I'm running an Avatar Mercury ultrabook with an elantech touchpad which refuses to support multitouch under 12.10.
When I hit 13.04, on top of continued multitouch issues, upon booting the mouse moves itself about 300px directly left every two seconds and clicks where it lands.  It will continue to march across the screen until it hits the side.  If I disable the touchpad through the keyboard shortcut, it stops.

I assume this is some sort of driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

To be short; no this is not an Ubuntu-problem.

What can you do ?

- do a fresh install of 13.04 (so avoid the problems one could have with an upgrade that went wrong)
- check in a live mode if the touchpad does the same tricky thing as before with your installation as now. If this happens = your touchpad has issues (what I don't know this you have to deal with yourself (maybe some liquid on the touchpad .... ) )

No way this is a **driver** issue.

Succes !

Comment: This is a fresh install.  Sorry, should have made that explicit...